# Core Plot line not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have created a simple implementation of the CorePlot framework. The chart shows up fine, but there is no line plotted. I have tried logging out my sample values and indeed do have data. Any and all input on why the line of plotted data does not show up would be appreciated!

**Header File:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PresentedViewControllerDelegate.h"
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

#define NUM_SAMPLES 30

@interface DeviceDetailModal : UIViewController <PresentedViewControllerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource>{
CPTXYGraph *graph;
NSMutableArray *samples;

double xxx[NUM_SAMPLES];
double yyy1[NUM_SAMPLES];

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PresentedViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

**Main File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DeviceDetailModal.h"
#import "DetailCell.h"
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

#define START_POINT 0 // Start at origin
#define END_POINT 15.0 // TODO time is 15 seconds

#define X_VAL @"X_VAL"
#define Y_VAL @"Y_VAL"

@implementation DeviceDetailModal


-(void)viewDidLoad{
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeView)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[self generateDataSamples];

NSNumber *xAxisStart = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:START_POINT];
NSNumber *xAxisLength = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:END_POINT - START_POINT];

double maxY = [[samples valueForKeyPath:@"@max.Y_VAL"] doubleValue];
NSNumber *yAxisStart = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-maxY];
NSNumber *yAxisLength = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2 *maxY];

CGRect hostingRect = CGRectMake(20, 330, 335, 347);


CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:hostingRect];

[self.view addSubview:hostingView];

graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostingView.bounds];

hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:xAxisStart
                                                length:xAxisLength];

plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:yAxisStart
                                                length:yAxisLength];

CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
dataSourceLinePlot.delegate = self;

// LINE STYLE
CPTMutableLineStyle *mainPlotLineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot dataLineStyle] mutableCopy];
[mainPlotLineStyle setLineWidth:2.0f];
[mainPlotLineStyle setLineColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]]];

[dataSourceLinePlot setDataLineStyle:mainPlotLineStyle];

// AXIS STYLE

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)[graph axisSet];

CPTXYAxis *xAxis = [axisSet xAxis];
CPTXYAxis *yAxis = [axisSet yAxis];
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
[axisLineStyle setLineWidth:1];
[axisLineStyle setLineColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]]];

[xAxis setAxisLineStyle:axisLineStyle];
[xAxis setMajorTickLineStyle:axisLineStyle];
[yAxis setAxisLineStyle:axisLineStyle];
[yAxis setMajorTickLineStyle:axisLineStyle];


[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
NSLog(@"PLOT: %@",dataSourceLinePlot);
[graph reloadData];

}


-(void)generateDataSamples{
double length = (END_POINT - START_POINT);
double delta = length / (NUM_SAMPLES -1);

samples = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NUM_SAMPLES];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
    double x = START_POINT + (delta * i);

    //X^2
    double y = x * x;

    NSDictionary *sample = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x],X_VAL,
                            [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y],Y_VAL,
                            nil];
    NSLog(@"SAMPLE: %@", sample);
    [samples addObject:sample];
}

[graph reloadData];


}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{
return NUM_SAMPLES;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
NSDictionary *sample = [samples objectAtIndex:index];

if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
    return [sample valueForKey:X_VAL];
}else{
    return [sample valueForKey:Y_VAL];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! The data source for the plot was not set, I had to do:

```
dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
```

I found this out when my numberOfRecordsPerPlot method was never being called.

Answer (score 0):

The default background fill is white and it doesn't look like you've changed it. The plot line is drawn with a white color so it doesn't show up on the white background. Try using the default line style or this:

```
mainPlotLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Sorry, to explain, my background is black. I did set the color of the plot line to white, but still no dice on getting it to show up. I have also changed the color of my view to see if the line is showing up in another color to no avail.

Comment: Check the `maxY` calculation and make sure it is correct.